# For what range of $a\in\Bbb R$ is $f(x)=ae^{-ax}$ in the unit ball with respect to the uniform metric on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces

For what range of $a\in\Bbb R$ is $f(x)=ae^{-ax}$ in the unit ball with respect to the uniform metric on $[0,1]$?

I.e when is $\|f\|_\infty\lt 1$

So far I see that for $a\ge 0$, $\|f\|_\infty=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|ae^{-ax}|=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}ae^{-ax}=a\lt1$ if $a\lt 1$, so we have: that $f$ is in the unit ball for $0\le a\lt 1$.

Then I considered $a\lt 0\Rightarrow \|f\|_\infty=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|ae^{-ax}|=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}-ae^{-ax}$

If we let $b=-a$ we seek $b\gt 0$ such that:

$\sup_{x\in[0,1]}be^{bx}\lt1$

Which is now where I am stuck, my assumption is that the value is maximised when $x=1$, which gives us:

$be^{b}\lt1$.

From looking around, the result references the W lambert function, but my issue is that this seems a little over complicated for something that was worth about $3$ marks in an exam paper (from a total of $90$ marks).

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: @DanielFischer thankyou, was a typo, it is meant to be $ae^{-ax}$

Comment: Hmm, yes, for an "exact" value, you'd need the Lambert $W$ function. For such low marks, I sort-of expect that $be^b < 1$ is a sufficient answer. Or maybe a numerical approximation.

Comment: @DanielFischer
It's a topology paper, so I doubt the numerical approximation, my only worry which may have lead to extra difficulty, is the fact that the value is always maximised by $x=1$, is this true?

Comment: When in doubt, differentiate.

Comment: @DanielFischer how would I find the local maximum in this fashion?

Comment: The derivative is (for $b > 0$) strictly positive. And the function is non-negative. Hence its maximal absolute value is attained at the right endpoint of the interval.

Comment: @DanielFischer
Of course! so indeed $x=1$ is a maximum, and I can see that we must have $b\lt1$ since if $b\ge1\Rightarrow \sup_{x\in[0,1]}be^{bx}\ge\sup_{x\in[0,1]}e^x=e\gt 1$

Comment: Yes. $b < \frac{5}{8}$ is still easy to see by hand, the approximation $0.5671432904097838$ of the bound not so easy.

Comment: @DanielFischer is there any errors in the assumptions I have made? This just seems like a lot, is all.